# Vector Proof Involving Triangle

Tags: proof-writing, vectors

I'm stuck on the following homework question:

> Given the triangle $PQR$, with $X$ placed on $PR$ dividing it into a ratio of $2:3$, and $Y$ the midpoint of $PQ$, prove that if $Z$ is the intersection point of $QX$ and $YR$, then it divides $YR$ into a ratio of $1:3$.

Note that this is to be solved purely with geometric vectors (i.e only vector addition, subtraction, and scalar multiplication). We may use dot product if it is advantageous to us, but in this case I don't think so.

The general proof for questions of this sort has been to first denote $\vec{ZR} = k\vec{YZ}$, then find sums of vectors equating to the zero vector (closed figures, e.g. $\vec{PY} + \vec{YZ} + \vec{ZX} - \vec{PX} = \vec{0}$), then equating those sums to each other to solve for $k$. I can't seem to find the right sums though. Or maybe this isn't the best approach.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think there is some ambiguity in your question. How could $Z$ be the midpoint of both $QX$ and $YR$. Even if I assume it is true, then again it is obvious from the fact that it will divide $YR$ into two equal parts, not in $1:3$ ratio.

Comment: Whoops, that's a mistake, thanks. Should make sense now.

Comment: $Z$ cannot be the midpoint of $QX$ as if that's the case $PX$ and $YZ$ would be parallel and $R$ won't even exist. I think you might mean $Z$ is the intersection of $YR$ and $QX$.

Comment: By the way, I have another doubt. How could you ensure that $Z$ will lie on both the lines i.e. it is the intersection of $QX$ and $YR$.

Comment: Another mistake. I wrote this question completely wrong wow. Lemme take another look and fix everything.

Comment: OH the issue was I used "midpoint" instead of "intersection point", which is why before it said $Z$ is the midpoint of both $QX$ and $YR$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**

1) Prove that WY is parallel to XZ.

2) Use the Thales theorem in the triangle $\mathop {WYR}\limits^\Delta$ which states $\frac{RX}{RW}=\frac{RZ}{RY}=\frac{3}{4}$.

[image]